# SWIG doesn't work on Windows with MinGW-w64 when binding C++ and Python: DLL load failed while importing: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, c++, windows, swig, mingw-w64

I am trying to bind C++ with Python on Windows using SWIG and MinGW-w64 g++. So far I got a factorial calculator function in C++:

```
// factorial.cpp
long fact(long num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return 1;
    return num * fact(num - 1);
}
```

This is my factorial.i:

```
%module factorial
%{
extern long fact(long num);
%}

extern long fact(long num);
```

I then use Command Prompt to build these:

```
swig -python -c++ factorial.i
```

This generates factorial_wrap.cxx and factorial.py.
I then use MinGW-w64 g++ to build these:

```
g++ -c factorial.cpp
g++ -c -fpic factorial_wrap.cxx -IC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include
g++ factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -LC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs -shared -lpython38 -o _factorial.pyd
```

So far no problem. The problem occurs when I then open up Python in Command Prompt and try to import these:

```
C:\Users\kritomas\Desktop>python
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import factorial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kritomas\Desktop\factorial.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _factorial
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _factorial: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

Here's the error, as you can see above.
I already tried Dependency Walker, that gave me 2 missing DLLs. After putting both of them into System32, it still happens.
I already tried using extern "C" instead of extern:

```
%module factorial
%{
extern "C" long fact(long num);
%}

extern "C" long fact(long num);
```

It just straight up removes fact():

```
C:\Users\kritomas\Desktop>g++ factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -LC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs -shared -lpython38 -o _factorial.pyd
factorial_wrap.o:factorial_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x38d7): undefined reference to `fact'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the same issue with Python 3.9.7, the only reason why I downgraded to 3.8.10 is because it runs perfectly on my Linux Mint VM (which has Python 3.8.10), if instead of running:

```
g++ -c -fpic factorial_wrap.cxx -IC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include
g++ factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -LC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs -shared -lpython38 -o _factorial.pyd
```

I run:

```
g++ -c -fpic factorial_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.8
g++ factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -shared -o _factorial.so
```

It works perfectly:

```
kritomas@kritomas-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import factorial
>>> factorial.fact(5)
120
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I am missing here? Please help me. Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Yes, -lpython38.

Comment: I compile factorial.cpp to factorial.o, no, I don't use any -l arguments there.

Comment: Thanks, will try that when I get to the computer ;)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I have the exact same issue :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met exactly the same problem after upgraded python to 3.9 on windows . After struggling for hours, I managed to solve it by manually copying some dlls from `***/mingw/bin/` where mingw32-g++ is found to where my `***.pyd` is located. I'm sure that `***/mingw/bin/` has been appended to %PATH%, but don't know why python3.9 couldn't find it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue migrating to clang/clang++

Install llvm:

```
choco install --yes llvm
```

and then, try:

```
clang++ -c factorial.cpp
clang++ -c factorial_wrap.cxx -IC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include
clang++ factorial.o factorial_wrap.o -LC:\Users\kritomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\libs -shared -lpython38 -o _factorial.pyd
```